# Резервные копии в android studio

Tags: android-studio

Можно ли и как настроить резервные копии проекта не на Git и прочие внешние хранилища, а на локальном диске?

*Использую Windows 7, если это важно.*

Comment: git - это система контроля версия, а не хранилище

Comment: @user7860670 Данивапрос! Внешняя система контроля версий = внешнее хранилище для резервных копий.

Answer (score 1):

Git и "внешние хранилища" это вещи перпендикулярные (Git и "резервные копии", в общем-то, тоже, если строго подходить к вопросу). Я, по вашей терминологии, использую git, но не использую "внешние хранилища". Просто не используйте внешний репозиторий и все. Или сделайте его в соседней папке/на соседнем диске. Примерно так:

```
[remote "host"]
    url = D:\\Repos\\Android\\MySuperPuperProject
```

Comment: Что значит "так"? Это где/куда прописать в AS?

Comment: это фрагмент гит-конфигурации для файла config, который позволит вам хранить резервную копию на внутреннем хранилище не отказываясь от всех преимуществ самого гита.

Comment: Где этот файл искать?  В какое место писать?